# 1024-bit SSL certificates provider

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

My service payment (iDeal Netherlands) only provide 1024-bit encryption.

What's the best 1024-bit SSL certificates provider ? (For example, I tried with godaddy.com/ssl but they only provide 2048-bit SSL certificates.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no good 1024-bit certificate provider. Such a weak certificate is worthless these days.

Comment: The Dutch banking online system is using 1024-bit certificate. I need a solution for the next months. Isn't there any 1024-bit SSL provider ?

Comment: They are not "worthless". There is a good performance argument to be made for 1024bit certificates (in fact this is why google.com currently uses 1024 bit certs)

Comment: @TonyK, "that means [...] that Google's security decisions are worthless". No, it means that the CAs that issued those fraudulent Google certificates are worthless. They probably have nothing to do with Google.

Answer (score 0):

Does your certificate need to be signed by a "real" CA?  If not I'd just generate my own 1024bit cert. As TonyK pointed out, 1024 is a fairly useless cert.

Answer (score 0):

There are still some certificate providers that will sign a 1024-bit certificate. If you are really only going to use it for a few months,  I would try RapidSSL or StartCom. The bit rate is determined by you when the CSR is generated. The certificate provider just decides whether they will sign it or not.