# Does Android have issues with 1024-bit certificates?

Tags: android, ssl-certificate

I have run into an issue where Android (versions 3.1 and 2.3.4) throws a:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
```

error accessing an RSS server that has a Versign V3 1024-bit certificate (CN = VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G2).  I can access a different server using a Versign V3 2048-bit certificate and it is fine.  Does anyone know if Android has issues with the older 1024-bit certficates?

The actual stacktrace looks like this:

```
08-01 08:24:54.390: ERROR/DownloadRssFeedTask(1260): Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
08-01 08:24:54.390: ERROR/DownloadRssFeedTask(1260):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:258)
08-01 08:24:54.390: ERROR/DownloadRssFeedTask(1260):     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:93)
08-01 08:24:54.390: ERROR/DownloadRssFeedTask(1260):     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:381)
08-01 08:24:54.390: ERROR/DownloadRssFeedTask(1260):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:164)
08-01 08:24:54.390: ERROR/DownloadRssFeedTask(1260):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
08-01 08:24:54.390: ERROR/DownloadRssFeedTask(1260):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
08-01 08:24:54.390: ERROR/DownloadRssFeedTask(1260):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
08-01 08:24:54.390: ERROR/DownloadRssFeedTask(1260):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
08-01 08:24:54.390: ERROR/DownloadRssFeedTask(1260):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
08-01 08:24:54.390: ERROR/DownloadRssFeedTask(1260):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
08-01 08:24:54.390: ERROR/DownloadRssFeedTask(1260):     at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:80)
08-01 08:24:54.390: ERROR/DownloadRssFeedTask(1260):     at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:46)
08-01 08:24:54.390: ERROR/DownloadRssFeedTask(1260):     at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:56)
08-01 08:24:54.390: ERROR/DownloadRssFeedTask(1260):     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:451)
08-01 08:24:54.390: ERROR/DownloadRssFeedTask(1260):     ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at this thread :

[1024-bit SSL certificates provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165218/1024-bit-ssl-certificates-provider)

It looks like it's just too weak to use 1024 bits ssl certificates. I looked at [the code from apache harmony](http://www.opensourcejavaphp.net/java/harmony/org/apache/harmony/xnet/provider/jsse/SSLSessionImpl.java.html) but the API seems to be a bit complex (and clumsy to be honest as some fields are modified outside the SSLImpl class), and I couldn't find much more information.

It looks like the best solution would be to ask for a modern 2048 bits x509 certificate form your web hosting provider.

Regards, 
 Stéphane

Comment: Yes, we have been upgrading our certs to 2048-bit but the particular server in this case has not been upgraded. I understand that the 1024-bit certs are weak but that should not invalidate that they are a good cert from an accepted provider.

Comment: In a security API, I assume it's a good choice not to support unsecure protocols...